# RDS Service Triggering Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and I was looking for a way to trigger Lambda from RDS Service in particular MYSql. Is there any way possible to achieve it? 
If not is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 14):

There are now multiple ways to trigger Lambda from both AWS RDS and AWS MySQL, but support varies between DB engines. Please see below edited section of this answer if you are actually curious about RDS Event messages processed by AWS Lambda.

---

**EDIT:**
If you are looking for a way for AWS Lambda to respond to [Event messages emitted by AWS RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html) (about the state of the cluster and not DB data events), please [read these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds.html). **NOTE:** Again, this has nothing to do with AWS Lambda invocation & responding to data manipulation events on DB tables/records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Based on list of RDS events (in AWS documentation), it seems there's no way for a Lambda to be called if data in an RDS database table has changed.  I'm looking for something similar to Dynamo DBStreams.  Does anyone know if something like DBStreams can be implemented for an RDS MySQL instance?

Comment: Hey @Chris, were you able to figure out how to invoke a lambda function if data in a RDS table changes?

Comment: You can use mySQL triggers along with LAMBDA_ASYNC() procedure or mySQL native function to achieve this effect.

Comment: This answer is out of date with reality as of 03/15/22. Please see below answer by @Desha for complete documentation for both Aurora and RDS offerings for both MySQL and RDS engines.

Comment: @garnaat, I think your answer was attempting to focus on subscribing AWS Lambda via AWS SNS topics to AWS RDS Event Notifications and not triggering Lambda based on the data events on DB tables/records which is OP's question. Therefore I made an edit.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using AWS Aurora, you can invoke an AWS Lambda function from by calling the `mysql.lambda_async` procedure.

Example:

```
CALL mysql.lambda_async (
  lambda_function_ARN,
  lambda_function_input
)
```

**lambda_function_ARN**

> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the Lambda function to invoke.

**lambda_function_input**

> The input string, in JSON format, for the invoked Lambda function.

**EDIT:**
More details available here: [Invoking a Lambda function from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)

Comment: is there similar function for RDS Postgres? Thank you

Comment: @Kostanos Sadly, there is currently no such functionality for Postgres RDS

Comment: @Kostanos, please check the answer below added by user Desha which I edited for more accurate documentation.

Comment: @Dimitriy Kankalovich, your comment is linking to the documentation for PostgreSQL triggering AWS Lambda in RDS, and the original question is about MySQL, so I have to flag it.

Comment: @Jim Geurts, your answer is for AWS Aurora which is somewhat relevant, but the OP question is about AWS RDS and MySQL engine specifically. 
Also the link in the docs is broken now and was wrong in the first place because you talk about Aurora and docs point to RDS, so I will edit to at least match docs for Aurora MySQL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html

Answer (score 9):

As of March 15th 2022, you can invoke an AWS Lambda function only from PostgreSQL engine in RDS but not from MySQL engine. The documentation is provided below:

1. [Invoking an AWS Lambda function from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html)

You can also invoke an AWS Lambda function from either MySQL or PostgreSQL engines in Aurora (NOTE: Aurora is different AWS service from RDS). The documentation for both is provided below:

1. [Invoking an AWS Lambda function from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html)
2. [Invoking a Lambda function from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)

Comment: If you down vote an answer please say why.

Comment: Wish there was a formal way to submit a feature request for MySQL RDS to invoke a lambda function.  For those with an enterprise support plan you can provide [feedback](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/send-feedback-aws) and for others you can use hashtag [#awswishlist](https://twitter.com/hashtag/awswishlist).